# Why I can't return function value? Return gives "none"?

Tags: python

```
def sel(unsort,current):
    if len(unsort) == 0:
        return current

    temp = unsort[0]    
    for i in range(len(unsort)):
        if unsort[i]<temp:
            temp = unsort[i];

    unsort.remove(temp)
    current = current + [temp];

sel(unsort,current)
```

### Above will define a function selection sort.

```
a = [4,3,2,1];
print(sel(a, []))
```

When I run the program on python, it print "None". The function should return `current` as a list. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly. The line `sel(unsort,current);` is indented wrong, it can't occur inside the function `sel()`. Also, Python doesn't use semicolons. And it doesn't use unnecessary parentheses, so `if len(unsort) == 0:` , without parens.

Comment: @smci Is there instruction on how to indent properly on the forum? It seems that when I put code in the post, it will not indent as I had on python. I see that semicolon is not used as terminator. Thanks.

Comment: Yes please read through [SO Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [Meta: How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Also (obviously), your function never returns anything, as @JonathonReinhart pointed out. The last line of a fn is typically a return statement. Otherwise, any local changes you make to a local copy of the `unsort` arg disappear when the fn ends, i.e. the result of the fn is thrown away, not what you want. See [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you recursively call `sel`, you ignore the return value.

Change it to `return`:

```
    return sel(unsort, current)
```